# How to update product quantity in session when same items are added to cart?

Tags: php, session, cart, shopping-cart

I am creating a cart using a session, but I don't know how to update product quantity when the same item is added to the cart session?

1. WhatsApp_add_cart function where I create session..
2. Get data from the hidden field...
3. WhatsApp_Cart_page where I display all session values using for each loop.

```
public function WhatsApp_Cart_button() {
        $whatsapp_names    = '';
        $whatsapp_price    = '';
        $whatsapp_quantity = '';
        $total_price       = '';
        $Whatsapp_id='';
        if ( isset( $_POST['WhatsApp_Cart_btn'] ) ) {

            if ( isset( $_POST['whatsapp_cart_nonce_field'] ) && wp_verify_nonce( sanitize_text_field( wp_unslash( $_POST['whatsapp_cart_nonce_field'] ) ), 'whatsapp_cart_field' ) ) {

                echo '';
            }

            if ( isset( $_POST['product_name'] ) ) {

                    $whatsapp_names = sanitize_text_field( wp_unslash( $_POST ['product_name'] ) );
            }
            if ( isset( $_POST ['product_price'] ) ) {

                    $whatsapp_price = sanitize_text_field( wp_unslash( $_POST ['product_price'] ) );
            }

            if ( isset( $_POST ['quantity'] ) ) {
                $whatsapp_quantity = sanitize_text_field( wp_unslash( $_POST ['quantity'] ) );
            }
                if ( isset( $_POST ['product_id'] ) ) {
                $Whatsapp_id = sanitize_text_field( wp_unslash( $_POST ['product_id'] ) );
            }
            $product_info = array( $Whatsapp_id,$whatsapp_names, $whatsapp_price, $whatsapp_quantity);

            $_SESSION['WhatsApp_cart'][] = $product_info;

        }
    }

    public function Whatsapp_cart_function() {

        global $product;
        if( $product->is_type( 'simple' ) ){
        $product_id   = $product->get_id();
        $product_name = $product->get_title();

                // $p_Desp =$product->get_description();.
        $final_price = $product->get_price();
        $button_cart = get_option( sanitize_text_field( 'WhattsApp_BtnTxt_cart' ) );
        ?>
<form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="hidden" name="product_id" value="<?php echo esc_html( $product_id ); ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="product_name" value="<?php echo esc_html( $product_name ); ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="product_price" value="<?php echo esc_html( $final_price ); ?>">
<?PHP

  if ( ! empty( $_SESSION['WhatsApp_cart'] ) ) {
            foreach ( $_SESSION['WhatsApp_cart'] as $key => $values ) {
   p_id=$values[0];
    if ( isset( $_GET['product_id'] ) ) {
  if($p_id==$_GET['product_id']){

  $_SESSION["WhatsApp_cart"][$key][$values[3]] + $_POST["quantity"];
    ?>                                                              
<input type="hidden" name="quantity" value="1" min="1" max="10" step="1" />

<?PHP
      } 
     ?>

        <?PHP
        } 
  ?>
  <?php
  } 
  ?>

     <input type="submit" name="WhatsApp_Cart_btn" style="background:#25d366; color: white;" value=" 
           <? 
       PHP 
          echo esc_html( $button_cart ); ?>" id="demo" onclick="Add_items();" />

        <?php wp_nonce_field( 'whatsapp_cart_field', 'whatsapp_cart_nonce_field' ); ?>
          </form>

            public function WhatsApp_cart_page() {

            if ( isset( $_GET['index_to_remove'] ) ) {
                unset( $_SESSION['WhatsApp_cart'][$_GET['index_to_remove']]);
                wc_add_notice('Item removed from cart successfully' , 'success');
            }
        ?>
<table class="" cellspacing="0">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="product_id"><?php esc_html_e( 'Remove product', 'Woo-WhatsApp' ); ?></th>
            <th class="product-name"><?php esc_html_e( 'Product', 'Woo-WhatsApp' ); ?></th>
            <th class="product-price"><?php esc_html_e( 'Price', 'Woo-WhatsApp' ); ?></th>
            <th class="product-quantity"><?php esc_html_e( 'Quantity', 'Woo-WhatsApp' ); ?></th>
            <th class="Total-price"><?php esc_html_e( 'Total', 'Woo-WhatsApp' ); ?></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <?php
        global $wp;
        if ( ! empty( $_SESSION['WhatsApp_cart'] ) ) {
            foreach ( $_SESSION['WhatsApp_cart'] as $key => $values ) {
                print_r( $_SESSION['WhatsApp_cart']);
                    $current_url    = home_url( $wp->request ); 
                    $remove_url     = $current_url . '?index_to_remove=' . $key;
                ?>
                <tr>
                    <th ><form action="" method="post"><a href="<?php echo esc_url($remove_url); ?> " name="index_to_remove" >X</a></form>
                    </th>
                    <?php echo '<th>' . esc_html( $values[1] ) . '</th>'; ?>
                    <?php echo '<th>' . esc_html( $values[2] ) . '</th>'; ?>
                    <th><input type="number" name="quantity" value="<?php echo $values[3]?>" min="0" max="10" step="1"> </th>
                </tr>
                
    <?php }
    ?>
                </table>

 <?php } ?>
```

Comment: You could use the product_id as key in your session array so you can easly find the product back in the cart. With key_exist you can check if it is already in your cart or not.

Comment: But you can better store the cart in the database and give the user an uniuqe and random generated cart id in a cookie. That way you have an better look on wat people add to there cart and the users cart get saved as long there cookie exist

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion.but i solved it match with the product id. See the Answer

Comment: I hope you recalculate the total price with data from the database when some one checksout. You save the price in the session that is posted so visitors can easly manipulate that value.

Answer (score 0):

```
$flag = false;
            if ( ! empty( $_SESSION['WhatsApp_cart'] ) ) {
                foreach ( $_SESSION['WhatsApp_cart'] as $key => $values ) {
                    $p_id     = $values[0];
                    $quantity = $values[3];
                    if ( $p_id == $whatsapp_id ) {
                        $flag                               = true;
                        $whatsapp_upquantity                = $whatsapp_quantity + $quantity;
                        $total_uprice                       = $whatsapp_upquantity * $whatsapp_price;
                        $product_info                       = array( $whatsapp_id, $whatsapp_names, $whatsapp_price, $whatsapp_upquantity, $total_uprice, $whatsapp_desp );
                         $_SESSION['WhatsApp_cart'][ $key ] = $product_info;
                    }
```